# ios: Change height of cell to size of text

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do I change the size of UITableView cell to the size of a NSString? I have tried the following and the size of the cell changes slightly but not to the full height of the text.

I have:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str = [_recipe.ingredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth-40, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [str sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height +35;
}
```

And:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = [_recipe.ingredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=1;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;

    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Cell Row #%d", [indexPath row]];

    return cell;

}
```

I get two warnings UILineBreakModeTailTruncated is depreciated.

How do I get the words to wrap.

Comment: Yes, implement your commented lines.

Comment: I have resorted to writing the string to a dummy label and taking the size of that label, when the "official" techniques did not work for one reason or another.

Comment: I figured it out just changed the depreciated value to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `[str sizeWithFont:]`. There are some other variations on this method that take into account a constrained width and line break mode. Look here to find something that will work: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html